# Is there a tool that allows you to custom build a vcproj?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

We have several Visual Studio projects, and we would like to:

- enable/disable some defines on some of the projects
- add/remove include paths
- change output directories ( lib dependencies ) for libs

In a nutshell, we would like to be able to support all of the things above, without having to have a lot of configurations in the solution file. Is there some tool which allows us to do that, perhaps from command-line, if VS doesn't support such a thing? We are using VS2005 Professional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use property sheets to share build settings accross several projects.  Projects can use multiple property sheets and property sheets can inherit from each other allowing you to mix and match however you need to.

In the build settings dialog for you project, you will need change the settings you are concerned about to `<inherit from project defaults>`.  In this context, default means to take the value from the property sheet.  Any default settings will appear non-bold, while settings that customized for the project are bold.

After that, you can change the values in the property sheets and have those changes applied to all the projects that use them at once.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) to generate a VS .sln and .vcproj files.

Comment: Absolutely. @Tempus, if you haven't tried CMake, I urge you to do so. I started using CMake in 2007 and today I would never create a VS project from within VS :)